# Executing Python File from A String Directory in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

Currently I am running a .py file at Jupyter Notebook using the following command:

```
!python /Users/manage.py /Users/u.data
```

Sometimes I have a really long file path. Thus, is there a way that I can execute it with anything similar to this?

```
path_name = "/Users/"
!python "{}manage.py".format(path_name) "{}u.data.format(path_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook will interpolate variables in magic commands if you prefix the variable name with `$`

```
path_name = "/Users/"
py_file = "{}manage.py".format(path_name)
data = "{}u.data".format(path_name)

!python $py_file $data
```